# handling multi threading to create password protected excel from result set

Tags: java, multithreading

We have a requirement to access excel export method which will connect to the database and write the result set to excel.

Multiple threads will access this method concurrently to create the password protected excel file. But we are facing issue with  java.lang.InterruptedException when multiple threads are trying to access this method.

can you please help in this issue.Below is the exportExcel method code.

```
public void exportTOExcel(ExportReport exportReport) {
        Connection connection = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            String fileName = exportReport.getReportName() + "_"
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("MMM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss_SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            String sheetName = exportReport.getReportName();
            connection = DatabaseConnection.openDBConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery(exportReport.getQuery());
            SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
            Sheet workSheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);
            DataFormat fmt = wb.createDataFormat();
            CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("@"));

            int rowNumber = 1;
            String excelFile = PropertyLoader.FILE_DOWNLOAD_PATH + "\\" + fileName + ".xlsx";
            while (rs.next()) {
                Row row = workSheet.createRow(rowNumber);
                for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    String value = String.valueOf(rs.getObject(i));
                    if (value == null) {
                        value = "";
                    }
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(i - 1);
                    cell.setCellStyle(this.stringCellStyle);
                    cell.setCellValue(value);
                }

                rowNumber++;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                workSheet.autoSizeColumn((short) i);
            }

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();

            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs, EncryptionMode.agile);

            Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
            enc.confirmPassword(exportReport.getPassword());

            OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(excelFile, PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
            OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
            opc.save(os);
            opc.close();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);
            fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: we have used ExecutorService to run the multiple threads concurrently. Each thread will have different details to get the connection to different database and write to excel.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a scenario. There are multiple people in a cafeteria wanting to drink Coffee. But the problem is there is only a single cup. So lets say 4 people come at different moments of time to drink the coffee. The first person comes and takes the cup , fill it up with coffee and start drinking it. Then, the second person comes and snatches the cup from him, throw away his coffee. He fills it up with coffee again and start drinking. So goes on. You can implement connection pooling to create and re-use connection as and when new thread comes. Define some scheduling mechanism.

Comment: we have used ExecutorService to run the multiple threads concurrently. Each thread will have different details to get the connection to different database and write to excel.